# Concavity/convexity of a function in a subset where the function is concave/convex

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Let $f:R^n \rightarrow  R$. Suppose $f$ is concave(convex) in $A\subseteq R^n$, where $A$ is open and convex. Moreover let us consider $B\subseteq A$, **closed**. Is $f$ concave/convex in that set ? Is it necessery that $ B $ is convex as well? ?

Comment: Talking about convexity/concavity of functions defined on non-convex sets is weird, because there will be some $x,y\in B$ and some $t\in(0,1)$ such that $tx+(1-t)y\notin B$, therefore making assertions about $f(tx+(1-t)y)$ completely meaningless.

Comment: Ok thank you, but what about the first question?

Comment: If you take as definition the same quantitative statement restricted to the instances that make sense, then of course it will be true a fortiori. Regardless of any topological properties of $B$.